# How to get previous error message after I fixed error

Tags: apache, google-chrome, tomcat, enterprise

Ok this sounds pretty dumb.

We use apache/tomcat @ my company for our products.

I was fixing an internal server error and pressed refresh on chrome.  It worked but now trying to make an internal article for my team and forgot what the second part of the error message said.

Is there anyway to see that previous page on Chrome.